# Check for key in csv file if key is matched then add data into different rows of matched column using python

Tags: python, csv, append

I have csv file like below

[image: CSV file]

I need to search for a key then some values should be added in that key column. for example I need to search for folder and some values should be added in folder column. in the same way I need to search for name and some values should be added in name column.

so the final output looks like below

[image: csv output file]

I have followed the below way but it doesn't work for me

```
import csv
list1 = [['ab', 'cd', 'ed']]
with open('1.csv', 'a') as f_csv:
    data_to_write_list1 = zip(*list1)
    writer = csv.writer(f_csv, delimiter=',', dialect='excel')
    writer.writerows(data_to_write_list1)
```

Comment: you can use Pandas.DataFrame to manage all csv operations easily.

Comment: I am pretty much new to python. could you share some code sample that how can we do that

Comment: There's an answer, if it wont satisfy you,i'll do so

Comment: @Eran Moshe - The answer is not working for me. can you share the sample.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only use built-in methods, you can get the first row of a file (in the case of a CSV file like yours, the headers) like this:

```
>>> with open('file_you_need.csv', 'r') as f:
>>>     file = f.readline()
```

In your case the variable file would then be (supposing the delimiter is ","):

```
folder,name,service
```

You can now do `file.split(",")` (eventually replacing "," with whatever your delimiter is) and you'll get back a list of headers. You can then create a list of lists where each list is a row of your file and write back to the file or use a dictionary to link new entries to each header. Depending on your choice you would then in different ways write back to the file, i.e. supposing you go with list of lists:

```
with open('file_you_need.csv','w') as f:
    for list in listoflists:
        row = ""
        for el, i in enumerate(list):
            if i != len(list):
                row += el+","
            else:
                row += el
        f.write(row)
```

As others have mentioned you could also use Pandas and DataFrames to make it cleaner, but I don't think this is too hard to grasp

Comment: @ Luca Giorgi - It is now working as per my requirement. the values are adding in single row in different columns. and in your code where are we searching for `folder` and `name`. can you update your answer properly as per my requirement

Comment: You don't need to look for anything, a CSV file is just a file where each row represents values and the first row is the headers of the file; hence all you need to do is write a new line "x,y,z" to update your CSV file with x showing up under the first header, y under the second and z under the third.